# c# SQL serverのエラー（エラーコード）を取得する方法を教えて下さい

Tags: c#, sql-server

c#でSQL serverへ接続してselect等の操作をする際にエラーが発生した場合、SqlException.Numberを取得すればSQL serverのエラーコードが分かると思って宜しいでしょうか？
それとも他にも情報があったりしますでしょうか？

エラーの内容をログ出力したいため質問させていただきました。

Oracleの場合は、ORAで始まるエラーコードを出力していましたが、SQL serverの場合は、それがSqlException.Numberに入ってくると考えています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Serverで発生するエラー](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/understanding-database-engine-errors?view=sql-server-2017)は

- エラー番号
- エラー メッセージ文字列
- Severity
- 状態
- プロシージャ名
- 行番号

で管理されています。C#からSqlClientで接続した際、このエラーは[`SqlError`クラス](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlerror?view=netframework-4.7.2)で表現され、[`SqlException`クラス](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception?view=netframework-4.7.2)の`Errors`プロパティに格納されています。
質問されているように`SqlException.Number`プロパティでも得られますが、正確には複数のエラーが格納されている可能性があることに注意してください。